# Reading text from a file in c

Tags: c, string, file, input, character

So I am trying to write a program that reads random lines of text from an input file. I can open the file but I dont know how to read characters yet, let alone character strings (only numbers so far). I am trying to make it so it can read in random lines of text and then I can manipulate them (i.e. print them in any order)

And is it possible for the program to recognize spaces (or even better periods) in between words in the input file? For example could I make it stop reading after the end of a sentence?

I am not so much looking for someone to write the code for me or anything, I am using this project as kind of a learning exercise so if anyone could tell me what topics in c to study to make this possible that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: read "file handling in c" .

Answer (score 0):

Reading your file with `fscanf()` is a good start. Have a look at the man page which will tell you how to read this either one variable at a time or many variables at a time. If your file is more free form than that, you may want to read the whole thing into memory and then process into tokens (perhaps using `strtok` or `strtok_r`), or use a combination of `fscanf` then process strings you have read with `strtok` or `strtok_r`. That should give you a start.

Comment: Use `fgets` instead of `fscanf` for reading your file line by line. It's much simpler.

Comment: Sure, but `fscanf` would allow the file to be read and separated by (e.g.) full stops / periods as OP suggested.